# Update SQL comand doesn't change the data

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sql-update, insert-update

I know may be it is stupid question. But This query doesn't work. I search solution more than 1 hour. 
Please Help

```
 public static bool ChangeEventStatus(Connector cn, EventData eventData)
    {
        int updatedRows = 0;

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Update EventList Set IsProcessed = ? Where EventId = ?";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("IsProcessed", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = true;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("EventId", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = eventData.EventId;


            updatedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        return (updatedRows == 1);
    }
```

What is wrong in my code. **ChangeEventStatus** method return true, but database records doesn't change.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you didn't refresh your table after changes?

Comment: I refresh it everytime

Comment: Sure the eventid is correct?

Comment: What type of database you are connecting to?

Comment: @AlexK. Yes I chack it everyTime

Comment: @AlexeySemidotsky MS SQL SERVER

Comment: I Use Windows Service.. Does It can affect the result

Comment: MSSQL doesn't use `?` as parameters.

Comment: Are you sure? @Crowcoder

Comment: @ElvinMammadov if you try to use SqlConnection and SqlCommand, the problem is solved ? Try it for experiment

Comment: @ElvinMammadov no, sorry, didn't notice OleDb at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static bool ChangeEventStatus(Connector cn, EventData eventData)
 {
        int updatedRows = 0;

         using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(someConnectionString));
        {
             conn.Open();
             using (OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
             {
                 cmd.CommandText = "Update EventList Set IsProcessed = ? Where EventId = ?";

                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsProcessed", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = true;
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = eventData.EventId;


                 updatedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        return (updatedRows == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure @ sign in adding parameter?

Comment: AFAIK it does not matter whether you put @ or not since parameters shall be defined in proper order; names are not important, it is the order that matters.

Comment: @ElvinMammadov code is not the same as it is opening a connection before executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. thanks everyone. I forgot commit transaction after updateting

Comment: In SQL Server transaction automatically commited after execute statement "Update EventList Set IsProcessed = ? Where EventId = ?" and a the test in my answer above show it. Do you have special settings on you SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a bit and wrote the test. All work fine.
Check:

- Connection string
- Is you pass correct EventId to function ?

  ```
  [TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      Assert.AreEqual(true, ChangeEventStatus(new EventData() {EventId = 3}));
    }

    private static bool ChangeEventStatus(EventData eventData)
    {
        int updatedRows = 0;

        using (var cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=FastExperiments;User Id = sa; Password = pass; "))
        {
          using (OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
          {
              cn.Open();

              cmd.CommandText = "Update EventList Set IsProcessed = ? Where EventId = ?";

              cmd.Parameters.Add("IsProcessed", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = true;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("EventId", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = eventData.EventId;

              updatedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
        }
        return (updatedRows == 1);
    }

    private class EventData
    {
      public int EventId { get; set; }
    }
  }
  ```